# Independence of events: text problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Can anyone look through this and tell me if there are any mistakes? Additionally, I don't know how to define $\Omega$ in this case. Thank you!

Two students meet up every week for doing their homework. There is a new exercise sheet every week and both of them try to remember to bring it along. Let $A$ be the event that the first student successfully remembers it and $B$ the event that the second student successfully remembers it. We assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same probability $\mathbb P(A)$ and $\mathbb P(B)$.

a) Every third meeting, both students bring the exercise sheet along. In one third of the cases, only one brings it along and every third time, noone brings it along. Prove that $A$ and $B$ cannot be independent.

Proof.

We have $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B), \mathbb P(A \cap B)=\frac{1}{3}, \mathbb P(\bar A \cap \bar B)=\frac{1}{3}, \mathbb P(\bar A \cap B)+\mathbb P(A \cap \bar B)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Let's assume, $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then $\mathbb P(A \cap B)=\mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(B)=(\mathbb P(A))^2$
$\implies \mathbb P(A) = \mathbb P(B)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

But: $\mathbb P(\bar A)\mathbb P(\bar B)=\mathbb P(\bar A)^2=(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^2\approx0,18\ne\frac{1}{3}=\mathbb P(\bar A \cap \bar B)$. So $A$ and $B$ must be dependent.

b) Assume that in every meeting they can work surely, with probability 1. Show that in this case, $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\mathbb P(A)=1$ or $\mathbb P(B)=1$.

Proof.

We have $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B), \mathbb P(A \cup B)=1$

"$\Rightarrow$"

$\mathbb P(A \cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A \cap B)\iff$

$1=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) \iff$

$1=\mathbb P(A)[1-\mathbb P(B)]+\mathbb P(B) \iff$

$1=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(\bar B)+\mathbb P(B) \iff$

$1-\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(\bar B) \iff$

$\mathbb P(\bar B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(\bar B) \overset{\mathbb P(\bar B)\ne 0, otherwise \mathbb P(B)=1 \Rightarrow done}{\iff}$

$1=\mathbb P(A)$

Similarly:

$1=\mathbb P(B)$

"$\Leftarrow$"

Let WLOG $\mathbb P(A)=1$. Then:

$\mathbb P(A \cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A \cap B) \iff$

$0=\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A \cap B) \iff$

$\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(A \cap B) \Rightarrow$

$\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(B)*1 = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(A \cap B)$

Comment: "every third meeting, both students bring the exercise sheet along.." That sounds a bit odd (especially the word "every"). Are you trying to say that the probability that both student bring the sheet equals $\frac13$? Same question for "every third time..".

Comment: This is the wording of the task, I wasn't sure how to interpret it but I thought this would indeed mean that the probability that both student bring the sheet equals $\frac{1}{3}$, that only one brings it equals $\frac{1}{3}$ and that no one brings it equals $\frac{1}{3}$.